# Remove Comments section from certain category posts

Tags: categories, comments

I'm trying to simply disable my comments section from one of my categories from showing up on my posts. How do I do this? Whats the code and where do I insert the code from a general standpoint? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.In your single.php find the location where it include the comment template.
    2. Then Check the category name of the post.
3. Use if else statement to check if its the category u want/not to display the comment and include it by desire.